# Custom scroll length for amp-carousel ad [AMP-HTML]

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, amp-html

This is my first time publishing a question, so forgive me if there's something wrong with it.

I'm currently working on a three-slide custom carousel ad template, using amp-carousel from project AMP.

I've made my template available to you via this link: https://jsfiddle.net/mlealrinaldi/6hvx15gb/

Among the premises of the project, there are two that are mandatory:

1) The second carousel slide has to be partially visible on the right corner when the first slide is displayed (to arouse the user's curiosity when seeing the ad).

2) In the desktop version, when using the 'next' and 'prev' buttons, the carousel should scroll to the center of the next or previous image in the sequence.

The problem I found was that **type="carousel"** allows me to partially display the next slide, but when I click the 'next' button, it does not scroll to the center of the next slide. It scrolls past beyond the center instead.

And when I use the **type="slides"**, the navigation buttons scroll correctly to the center of the next slide but does not allow me to display part of the next slide (only one slide at the time).

I'm looking for a solution that contemplates these two requirements. For reference, here's a link to amp-carousel documentation: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-carousel#type

This is the part of the HTML that contains the carousel:

```
              <amp-carousel height="245" layout="fixed-height" type="carousel">

                <div class="slide" id="slide1" style="margin-left: 20px">
                    <img height="170" width="200" src="slide0.png"/>
                    <div>
                            <div class="cta" style="float:left"><p>São 100 carros todos os dias</p></div>
                            <div style="float:left;margin-top: 10px">
                                <a href="http://www.google.com.br" target="_blank">Participe</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="slide" id="slide2">
                    <img height="170" width="200" src="slide1.png"/>
                    <div>
                            <div class="cta" style="float:left"><p>Se ligar, é seu!</p></div>
                            <div style="float:left;margin-top: 10px">
                                <a href="http://www.google.com.br" target="_blank">Participe</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slide" id="slide3">
                    <img height="170" width="200" src="slide0.png"/>
                    <div>
                            <div class="cta" style="float:left"><p>Faça o teste drive.</p></div>
                            <div style="float:left;margin-top: 10px">
                                <a href="http://www.google.com.br" target="_blank">Participe</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </amp-carousel>
```

I've also tried to look into the .js AMP functions that listen to the click on the navigation buttons, and make the carousel work, but my limited knowledge only took me so far.

Comment: can you please share desktop view fiddle.